# storing escape characters in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, special-characters

I want to be able to store some special characters like "\r\n" in MySQL database. So I'm trying to do something like that: 
insert into config( key, value) values('end.of.line.symbols', '\r\n')

Then in my Java code I'm trying to read this property and use it for writing in file:

```
String endOfLineSymbols = "select from config where key = 'end.of.line.symbols'"...
String helloWorld = "Hello, world!";

//writes the specified string to the file + end of the line symbols
writeToFile(helloWorld, endOfLineSymbols);
```

Then in the file I see:

> Hello, world!\r\n

So these symbols are not recognised as a line break but just as a simple string.

Is it possible to resolve it somehow?

Thanks, cheers, Andrey

Comment: Where are you invoking that insert statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) like:

```
String str = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(rs.getString("myColumn"));
```

The method `escapeJava()`:

> Escapes the characters in a String using Java String rules.

**EDIT:**

If you dont want it to be escaped then try this:

```
String str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(rs.getString("myColumn"));
```

Comment: Now prints 'Hello, World!\\r\\n'

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky:- Correct me if i am wrong but that is what you asked for? Or do you want to escape the `\n\r`?

Comment: the problem is that in text editors these symbols are recognized not as a end of the line symbols, but as a simple string. I.e. I want to find a way to make text editors think about these symbols as about end of the line characters

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky:- Then you need simply: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(rs.getString("myColumn"));`